# why sometimes we need to mount those files under root?

Tags: linux

I am a newbie to mount. From what I know, the root file / is automatically mounted to /dev/xvda1 or /dev/sda1. In some of the tutorials, people mount file like /dummy to /dev/xvdb1, I don't understand what the meaning of doing this. Because it's parent root file / has already mounted. Could someone explain this to me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW, mounting the root isn't always quite as "automatic" as all that. The device *can* be specified on the kernel command line in some circumstances, but more frequently in real-world systems it's located and mounted by code in your initrd or initramfs -- which is to say that if you're maintaining a Linux distro, building an embedded device, &c. then you may be charged with writing that code, making it not "automatic" from your perspective at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To throw out a very non-exclusive list of possibilities:

- Sometimes `/` doesn't have the capacity for what you intend to use it for, so you want to use a filesystem located on a different physical device for extra storage.
- Sometimes you want to mount content from a filesystem that isn't *capable* of being used as root -- for instance, a FAT or NTFS filesystem, which doesn't properly support UNIX semantics.
- Sometimes your other block device is removable, and you're mounting it only temporarily.
- Sometimes your other block device is located on media that isn't available at boot time -- requiring iSCSI setup or other operations that prevent it from being used as root without initrd / initramfs facilities your operating system doesn't provide.
- Sometimes you want to use a different filesystem with different semantics -- for instance, maybe your `xvdb1` is a GFS shared-block filesystem that other machines also have mounted at the same time for combined storage.
- Sometimes you have a read-only block device with bulk contents that can't change, and you're mounting it to multiple VMs, vs systems having their own local read-write storage.

The number of possibilities is nearly endless.

This isn't a software development question, and doesn't belong on StackOverflow.